# React native Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app' when run-android

Tags: react-native

I jus started to setup development environment for react-native-cli. I was followed the instruction on the document on this link:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

but i got error message when i start to run my sample project. 
I got this message: Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app' when i executed this command: 'react-native run android'.

what can i do to solved this error.

thx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Opening `android` directory in Android Studio and building there does the trick.